# Подскажите, как добавить php скрипт в статью вордпресс

Tags: php, wordpress

Добавил в public_html папку img, содержащую скрипт выбора шрифтов. При заходе на www.mysite.ru/img отображается:
[image: скрин 1] 
Содержимое папки img:
[image: скрин 2]
Нужно сделать так, чтоб этот скрипт выводился внутри статьи. Я совсем не шарю, подскажите, пожалуйста.

index.php:

```
<?
$fonts = file('fonts.txt');

$name = $_GET['name'];
if($name=='')
    $name = 'Введите текст';

echo '<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<title>Выбор шрифта</title>     
<style>
    body{
        font:10px Verdana, sans-serif;
        color:#464544;
    }
    a{
        font:10px Verdana;
        color:#464544;
        margin:0 5px;
    }
    .imgfonts img{
        font:10px Verdana;
        color:#464544;

    }
    .imgfonts p{

        padding:5px 0;
    }
    input{
        font:16px Verdana, sans-serif;
        padding:5px;

    }
    h2{
        font:26px Verdana, sans-serif;
        color:#464544;
    }
    h2 a{
        font:26px Verdana, sans-serif;
        color:#464544;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="allfonts">
<h2><a href="./">Выбор шрифта</a></h2>
    <form action="./" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Любое слово" />
    <input type="submit" value="Посмотреть">
    </form>
';


for($i=0;$i<count($fonts);$i++)
{
    $font = explode(":",trim($fonts[$i]));
    $fname = $font[0];
    $file = $font[2];

    echo "<p><img src='img.php?f=".$i."&s=".$name."'/><p>Шрифт: ".$fname." </p><HR>";



}







echo $end;
echo '</body>

</html>';


?>
```

img.php:

```
<?

$fonts = file('fonts.txt');

$fi = $_GET['f'];

$font = explode(":",$fonts[$fi]);

$inFontSize = $font[1];
$inFontFile = 'ttf/'.trim($font[2]);

$inText = $_GET['s'];




$bbox = imagettfbbox($inFontSize, 0, $inFontFile, $inText);
$width = abs($bbox[0]) + abs($bbox[2]);
$height = abs($bbox[5]) + abs($bbox[1]);
$x = abs($bbox[0]);
$y = abs($bbox[5]);

header('Content-type: image/png');
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

$text_colour = imagecolorallocate($img, $redColor, $greenColor, $blueColor);
$background = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($img, ($redColor == 255 ? 254 : $redColor + 1), ($greenColor == 255 ? 254 : $greenColor + 1), ($blueColor == 255 ? 254 : $blueColor + 1), 127);

imagefill($img, 0, 0, $background);
imagecolortransparent($img, $background);

myimagettftext($img, $inFontSize, 0, $x, $y, $text_colour, $inFontFile, $inText, $inAlign, $width, $height);
imageAlphaBlending($img, false);
imageSaveAlpha($img, true);
imagepng($img);

imagecolordeallocate($img, $text_colour);
imagecolordeallocate($img, $background);
imagedestroy($img);

function myimagettftext(&$image, $size, $angle, $left, $top, $color, $font, $text, $align, $width, $height) {

    $text_lines = explode("\n", $text);

    if ($align == ALIGN_LEFT || count($text_lines) <= 1) {
        imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $left, $top, $color, $font, $text);
    } else {
        $lines = array();
        $line_widths = array();
        $line_heights = array();
        $line_ys = array();
        $sum_height = 0;

        foreach ($text_lines as $index => $block) {
            $dimensions = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $block);

            $line_width = abs($dimensions[0]) + abs($dimensions[2]);

            $line_height = abs($dimensions[5]) + abs($dimensions[1]);

            $line_y = abs($dimensions[5]);
            $lines[$index] = $block;
            $line_widths[$index] = $line_width;
            $line_heights[$index] = $line_height;
            $line_ys[$index] = $line_y;
            $sum_height += $line_height;
        }

        $max_width = max($line_widths);
        $max_width = $max_width + floor(($width - $max_width) / 2);

        $delta_h = floor(($height - $sum_height) / (count($lines) - 1));
        $top_offset = 0;
        $left_offset = 0;
        foreach ($lines as $index => $line) {

            if ($align == ALIGN_CENTER) {
                $left_offset = ($max_width - $line_widths[$index]) / 2;
            } elseif ($align == ALIGN_RIGHT) {
                $left_offset = ($max_width - $line_widths[$index]);
            }

            imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $left_offset - $left, $line_ys[$index] + $top_offset, $color, $font, $line);

            $top_offset += (isset($line_heights[$index]) ? $line_heights[$index] : 0) + $delta_h;
        }
    }
}

$redirect = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']:'redirect-form.html';
header("Location: $redirect");
exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Возможностей сделать это много. Например создать шорткод и его выводить в контенте там, где это надо.

В `functions.php` вашей темы добавьте:

```
add_shortcode('font-form', 'font_form_callback');
function font_form_callback(){
     require ABSPATH . 'img/index.php';
}
```

Теперь в контенте(в админке) добавьте сам шорткод: `[font-form]`

Comment: Все сделал так, сохраняю статью и выдает критическую ошибку.

Comment: В каждой ошибке написано, что пошло не так

Comment: https://pixs.ru/image/Ds1VB

А где посмотреть можно, что за ошибка? На почте ничего нету.

Comment: включите дебаг на сайте и увидите ошибку

Comment: https://pixs.ru/image/DD9Zj

Comment: ну вы подключаете что-то непонятное. Откуда в пути NaN?

Comment: Все сделал, как вы написали. Что за NaN я не знаю. 39 строчка - require ABSPATH . img/index.php;

Comment: img/index.php нужно в кавычки взять

Comment: https://pixs.ru/image/DDapR

Answer (score 0):

Если это нужно только для одной страницы, то возможно лучше и проще будет создать свой шаблон с имеющимся кодом
См https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/